# Issues with network based directory as compared to local for python os.chdir

Tags: python, networking, import, active-directory

This question is very closely related to my previous post about search a directory for certain files (excel) and loading many excel files into a dataframe. While I got that code to work, I am trying to add an option to the code to change directory. I am using os.chdir(). My issue is when I am trying to read the files it appears that the read_excel() function is picking up the old local drive rather than the one out on the company server. Code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

os.chdir(r"N:\IT\Public\MCF\Global\Metrics\2020")
#os.chdir(r"C:\Users\tony\PycharmProjects\Metrics")  #old path

path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)
print(path)

files_xlsx = [f for f in files if f[-4:] == 'xlsx']

df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in files_xlsx:
    data = pd.read_excel(f,"Metrics")
```

Basically the os.getcwd() renders correctly but when I go to read_excel I get the error:
Invalid path or file name "C:\Users\Metrics202001.xlsx" is not found. Not sure why this is happening but would appreciate some direction.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not passing the full path to `pd.read_excel()` and are instead relying on the location being picked up from the context?

Comment: Try to use the UNC path instead of N:

Comment: @BoarGules when I try to add full path via something like os.path.join(path,f) within read_excel() in my code I get an error saying bad zip file; unable to open. I have read this is a version issue with pandas but in any event I cannot get it to work.

Comment: @rfkortekaas I have tried what I think is the UNC path (starts with \\) and that hasn't worked either. Granted I did not try to use os.path.join but still. It is difficult to find UNC path given the environment I am in.

Comment: @rfkortekaas I have tried the UNC path both with and without os.path.join(). Using os.path.join(path,f) I get zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file as mentioned above to BoarGules. Using the code with changing the cwd to the UNC I get the same error.

Comment: UNCs begin with 2 slashes, 4 if you need to escape them. You can find out what UNC the mapping N: corresponds to by typing `net use N:` at a Windows console command prompt. I believe the message you get from the explicit path is likely to be a better indication of what is really wrong.

Comment: Or you can use `Path(file_path).resolve()` to get the UNC path of the complete path.

Comment: Thank you both. I am using win32wnet package to get UNC via WNetGetUniversalName. When I put in, it looks like the dataframe doesn't populate for some reason. any idea? @rfkortekaas. When I run the code I get the following output - "C:\Users\tony\PycharmProjects\Metrics\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/tony/PycharmProjects/Metrics/main.py"
\\ctSTOR01\Groups\IT\Public\MCF\Global\Metrics\2020
[] - this is the list of excel files that should populate. I am not sure why the C file populates in blue at the top of output window either

Comment: I do not totally understand your comment; which is mentioned in blue? But the result starting with `\\ctSTOR01\...\2020` is the UNC Path. Try to use this with `os.chdir`.